# gdb setting fs register on Linux

Tags: linux, gdb, x86-64

I'm debugging an ELF 64-bit binary using `gdb` and I notice that the `%fs` register is set to `0x63`. For some testing that I'd like to perform I'd like to set the `%fs` register to `0x00`.

I tried doing a `set $fs=0x0` but the value wouldn't change. In some cases I got a:

```
Couldn't write registers: Input/output error.
```

Is there any way I could set the value for the `%fs` register? I'm also open to modifying the binary, adding inline assembly to the source, etc.

**EDIT** : Currently, I'm trying this out by attaching to a process rather than running it from within `gdb`.

A screenshot to illustrate the problem :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Low 2 bits have to be set or you will get an `EIO` error. Only the low 16 bits manage to get set anyways.

Snippet from `arch/x86_64/kernel/ptrace.c`:

```
case offsetof(struct user_regs_struct,fs):
    if (value && (value & 3) != 3)
        return -EIO;
    child->thread.fsindex = value & 0xffff; 
    return 0;
```

That said, setting to `0x00` shouldn't be problematic per the code and per my testing.

```
(gdb) set $fs=3
(gdb) info register fs
fs             0x3      3
(gdb) set $fs=1
Couldn't write registers: Input/output error.
(gdb) set $fs=0
(gdb) info register fs
fs             0x0      0
(gdb) set $fs=0xffffffff
(gdb) info register fs
fs             0xffff   65535
```

Comment: would this behavior vary if a process were being traced?